# How to dynamically allocate function code?

Tags: c, pointers, callback, function-pointers

In the C language, the usual route for function pointers as callbacks from some library is to include a `void*` pointer for the context of the user:

```
void (*fp)(void* ctx);
```

The allows the library to call the callback with context `ctx`.

Let's say I'm using a library that does not include a context pointer in the callbacks. I will need to have one callback for each context. What is the most portable way to dynamically allocate function pointers in C for providing callbacks? How can I `malloc()` a function code that can be called from the library?

For example:

```
typedef void (*my_fp_t)(char);

my_fp_t fp = (my_fp_t) malloc(sizeof(...));
init_function_ptr(fp, "Hello, there");
my_library_callback(fp);
...

void my_library_callback(my_fp_t fp) {
  fp('a'); // prints "Hello, there"
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186682/discussion-on-question-by-vz0-how-to-dynamically-allocate-function-code).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you wish to allocate the actual function code, rather than the function pointer. The way this is done when writing bootloaders and similar:

- Be dead certain about the underlying calling convention used by the compiler and ABI. You'll need to know exactly which registers and/or places in the stack frame where everything goes upon function call and return.
- Generate the assembler code either by writing a function in the C compiler and carefully copy/paste the assembly, or by manually writing the function in assembler.
- Translate assembler to op codes.
- Ensure there's a chunk of memory where you can both store data and execute code. This is also up to the ABI and the MMU setup.
- Find out how to allocate memory in this custom segment. Typically involves some linker script fiddling and various non-standard keywords. `#pragma __declspec __attribute__` blabla with sugar on top. Highly compiler-specific.
- Allocate memory to this area as a raw `uint8_t func [n]` array, containing the raw OP codes in hex.
- Shut off strict aliasing and other such evil pointer conversion things. Ensure that your compiler has some well-defined, non-standard extension when going from object pointers to function pointers.
- Call the code through `((func_ptr)func) ()`.

As you hopefully can tell, this can be quite a task, depending on system. For small microcontrollers using embedded systems compilers, it is somewhat easily achievable. For more intricate systems like x86 or PowerPC, using compilers like gcc, far less so. You'll be relying on various poorly-specified behavior and the code will be completely system-specific.

Comment: So all in all this sounds like: "Let it be." ;-)

Comment: @alk Depends on the system. I've written various bootloader stuff like this for low-end microcontrollers, where it isn't too painful. When you need to execute code from RAM instead of flash etc. But doing something similar on a high-end CPU would be another story.

Comment: @Lundin Can't I just write a "template" function and then malloc+memcpy the code of the function with local variables initialized to a known value, and update some local variables values with search and replace?

Comment: @vz0 If ignoring pointer conversion issues, how would you know the size of the function, where it ends etc? And it isn't obvious that you'll be able to find the values you are looking for in an optimized C function. Something like `void f (void) { size_t n=5; ... switch(n) { case 5: do_stuff(); break } ... }` might get translated into "call do_stuff" and there won't be a 5 to find anywhere in the machine code.

Comment: @Lundin I was thinking more on the lines of `void f (void) { void* n = 0x4242424242424242; do_stuff(n); }` then I would just search and replace for 0x4242424242424242. Calling __builtin_object_size from GCC doesn't work for function objects, tho :(

Comment: @Lundin anyway, thanks for your detailed answer, I think I got a workaround already. Will post it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got an answer.

The real problem is getting a `void*` context pointer inside a callback that does not receives one. And I can't use (in principle) global variables because there are potentially many callbacks being called, and I can't identify which is the one.

I could take the same route as a JIT VM: generating machine code dynamically for each possible void* ctx value, such as:

```
void do_stuff(void* ctx) {
  // Finally have the ctx!
}

void* my_ctx;
my_fn_ptr p = allocate_function_that_calls_f_with_ctx(do_stuff, ctx);
library_register_callback_fn(p);
```

Here `p` is a function pointer for a function with a signature `void (*)(void)`, that when called in turns it calls `f(ctx)`.

However, this is just for a callback for a library, and the number of callbacks is small. I could then write a bunch of functions, each one taking a void* from a table, each one from a different index:

```
void do_stuff_0(void) { do_stuff(do_stuff_TABLE[0]); }
void do_stuff_1(void) { do_stuff(do_stuff_TABLE[1]); }
void do_stuff_2(void) { do_stuff(do_stuff_TABLE[2]); }
...
```

I can write some simple script that writes in a new .c file all the functions that go from 0 to a couple of thousands. Then I would need to keep track which functions are already registered and which ones are not, and provide some mechanism to both pick the next available and free those which are not needed anymore.