# Calling buffer as a function in C?

Tags: c, pointers

```
char buf[sizeof(shellcode)];
strcpy(buf, shellcode);
((void(*)())buf)();
```

I'm having a hard time to understand the syntax of the third line, I think it is making a buffer a function?

Comment: The third line is casting the buffer to a function which doesn't look valid.

Comment: Local variables (including arrays) are usually put on the stack by the compiler. Few operating systems would make the stack executable, so you can't "call" it anyway.

Comment: This is valid if a) you make some assumptions about compiler behavior which are reasonable but not part of the C standard, b) `shellcode` has valid binary code for this processor, and c) the OS and CPU don't mark certain areas of memory as non-executable.

Comment: @SPlatten. Looks fine if that's the right type for `shellcode`

Comment: @OP what's the declaration of `shellcode`?

Comment: @Daniel. It could just be copying a pointer, but `strcpy` does not look like the right choice at all.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I don't understand how buf can be called as a function, there is no code associated with buf.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I was assuming `buf` would decay to a pointer before the cast, so you're actually calling into `buf` as though it were a function. Are you saying it wouldn't?

Comment: @DanielH. I'm looking for the authoritative source, but I'm pretty sure it always gets upcast to a pointer to a function.

Comment: @DanielH, It is a way of Buffer overflow attack. If you compile with making stack executable, you can execute a code inside the stack in this case, the code inside buf(assembly of shell program).

Comment: `strcpy` will stop at the first zero. Consider `memcpy`

Comment: which zero @Jean-FrançoisFabre?

Comment: @SPlatten : you might want to read up on [shellcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode). When an attacker manages to place such shellcode in a certain memory location, and manages to overwrite a function pointer with that memory location, the shellcode will be executed whenever that function pointer is called (keeping in mind all caveats mentioned by others).

Comment: if `shellcode` contains a zero, it will stop _before_ the end, It's used to copy nul-terminated strings, not buffers. if it doesn't contain a zero it will overflow. Use `memcpy`

Comment: when in doubt about a type, use [cdecl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cdecl): https://cdecl.org/?q=%28void%28%2A%29%28%29%29buf

Comment: This probably won't work on most systems. There's lots of things to consider, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54183237/584518

Comment: @Lundin, it works on my PC by compiling using, `gcc -m32 -z execstack -o shell  shell.c`, command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct about the third line. It takes `buf`, decays it to a pointer, and then casts that pointer to a pointer-to-function. Then it calls that function. This works because `void(*)()` means "pointer to a function accepting no parameters and returning `void`", and wrapping it in parentheses turns it into a cast. You now have a pointer-to-function, which you can call as though it were a regular function name.

This is not allowed by the C standard, but based on how compilers work will probably mean that it treats the address of `buf` as the address of a function in memory and tries to call that function. Usually this wouldn't work because the OS would tell the CPU to mark the region of memory `buf` is in as not executable, so when you try to pretend it's a function the CPU will throw an error; let's assume that the OS doesn't do this or that you have an old enough CPU that it doesn't support that.

You don't show us the contents of `shellcode`. Since everything in a computer is just a sequence of bytes, including the compiled binary code your computer runs, `shellcode` might contain executable binary code. If it does, then this causes that code to start running.

For example, if you compiled

```
void mycode()
{
    puts("Hello, world!");
}
```

you could then extract the contents of function `mycode` from the resulting object file. If you put those contents into `shellcode`, then the code in your question would (assuming the compiler treats pointers-to-function and pointers-to-data the same, and that the OS or CPU doesn't support noexec memory) print `Hello, world!` to the screen.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel H.